# Insert into table_name values () (select ...)

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to insert select queries into many-to-many relationship table.

```
Table A
id, name

Table B
id, name

Table A_B
a_id, b_id


insert into A_B (a_id, b_id) 
 values(select a.id from a where a.name = 'a_name', -- this query always returns one result
        select b.id from b where b.name = 'b_name') -- this query returns multiple results
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but you need a separate set of parentheses for the subqueries.  *And* the subqueries need to return one row:

```
insert into A_B (a_id, b_id) 
    values ( (select a.id from a where a.name = 'a_name'),
             (select b.id from b where b.name = 'b_name')
           )
```

However, this is usually accomplished using a `join`:

```
insert into A_B (a_id, b_id) 
    select a.id, b.id
    from a join
         b
         on a.name = 'a_name' and b.name = 'b_name';
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. First query is static and the second returns more multiple values